# How to diagnose a member variable being set to zero randomly in segment of code?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, stack-overflow, undefined-behavior

I can't show the whole code (and it's physically impossible for me to do anyway) that caused this issue, and I think actually solving this problem is likely going to be out of scope here. So the question I'm asking is *how* I can diagnose this issue.

Basically I have a class that looks like this (note that I'm *not* able to reproduce the issue I had with a MVCE, so I'm just showing approximately what I'm doing, so that I can get help with the *tools* I need to debug):

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <semaphore> 
#include <thread> 

struct SharedDataStructure{
    SharedDataStructure(){
         for(auto& value : semaphore_array){
             value = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<std::counting_semaphore<2>>(2); 
         }
    }
    std::uint32_t get_latest_index(){... calculates some index}; 
    std::array<std::atomic<uint32_t>,16> atomics_member; 
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<std::counting_semaphore<2>, 16> semaphore_array; 
    std::uint32_t dummy0;

}


struct ThreadClass{
    ThreadClass(std::atomic<bool>& stop_flag, SharedDataStructure& shared_data_structure){
        auto thread_function = [&shared_data_structure, control_toke](){
            ...

            ... create socket
            
            std::array<mmsghdr, 1024> msgvec; 
            std::array< iovec, 1024> iovecs; 
            auto thread_socket = socket(...);
            ... //initialize  initilaize mmsghdr and iovecs up here
            ... //set thread_socket options, bind to (0.0.0.0) and some port here etc.. 
            timespec timeout = {}; 
            timeout.tv_sec = 1; 
            while(!stop_flag){
                // up until this point, shared_data_structure.semaphore_array is filled with what appear to be actual normal pointers. 
                auto packet_count = recvmmsg(thread_socket, msgvec.data(), msgvec.size(), 0, timeout); 
                // after this point, shared_data_structure.semaphore_array is filled with nullptrs, as if somethign zeroed all the values out. 
                for(std::size_t i = 0; i < packet_count; ++packet_count){
                    auto index = shared_data_structure.calculate_latest_index(); // in debugger this is 1, so no out of bounds
                    //causes segmentation fault, because for some reason now all the pointers in semaphore_array are nullptr...
                    shared_data_structure.semaphore_array[index].aquire(); 
                    //do something here. 
                    shared_data_structure.semaphore_array[index].release();
                }
            }
        }
        m_thread = std::thread(thread_function); 
    }
    ~ThreadClass(){
        m_thread.join(); 
    }
    std::thread m_thread; 

}

void create_thread_class(std::atomic<bool>& stop_flag){
    SharedDataStructure shared_data_structure;
    ThreadClass thread_class_0(stop_flag, shared_data_structure); 
    //ThreadClass thread_class_1(stop_flag, shared_data_structure); happens whether this is commented out or not. 
    while(!stop_flag.load()){
        //... at this point this just became an empty loop for debugging. 
    }
}
//invoke create_thread_class in a thread on it's own later.
```

Before this line of code:

```
 auto packet_count = recvmmsg(thread_socket, msgvec.data(), msgvec.size(), 0, timeout);
```

`SharedDataStructure::semaphore_array` contains a bunch of "real" pointers, just like I initialized.  But after, all the pointers become nullptr. Note none of the other value in the structure seem to be effected.

I'm lost on how I even debug this.  It's clear that `recvmmsg(...)` should have *zero* effect on a member of a class that's not used inside of it.  I think there's some sort of undefined behavior I'm invoking, but I don't know how I can even find it. The result looks similar to a buffer overflow, but I don't understand how that would effect a stack variable (I don't think recvmmsg is doing copious amounts of things on the stack?).

**What can I do to diagnose this type of issue?**

Comment: Looks like time to brush up on the debugger's capabilities. On Linux, I can instruct `gdb` to place a hardware watch on a variable, that gets tripped whenever it changes, for any reason. So, I would just punch a few buttons, type `c` to continue, let the code run and `gdb` pause execution as soon as something touches the memory location being watched.

Comment: Q: Is the data that's mysteriously being set to zero in a shared memory segment?  Is it shared between different processes?  What's the OS?  Q: What compiler/debugger are you using? STRONG SUGGESTION: consider debugging your program and setting a watch.

Comment: As SamV mentioned, what you are looking for is a "watchpoint", and most good debuggers are capable of this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How would I figure out what function triggered it assuming I've watched the variable?

Comment: @paulsm4 No, it's all within the same process, the only things that touch the variable are the equivalent to  `create_thread_class` function (which is run as it's own thread, the `thread_class_0` which launches it's own thread and `thread_class_1`, but I stopped everything but `thread_class_0` from actually using editing the value when debugging, and the same thing happened (so it's referenced in `create_thread_class` but only to pass it to another thread by reference, it is not read or edited in there from that point on)

Comment: The debugger will halt the program and show you the line of code that did the write. It may not be that helpful because it could be deep in some library function, but you can use the call stack (`bt` command in gdb) to see how the program got into that library function (assuming the mistake doesn't turn out to also be demolishing the stack along with the variable you're watching).

Comment: Given that `recvmsg` can return negatives, your loop is pretty dangerous. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/57oPobr7f). Also, you're doing `++packet_count` instead of `++i` which really isn't gonna help.

Comment: In regards to not having a mcve, you can still use working on that to narrow down the issue.  Keep cutting out code until the problem stops, revert one step, then working on debugging that smaller program

Comment: @Krupip *How would I figure out what function triggered it assuming I've watched the variable?* -- Use the call stack.  But beware -- the watchpoint isn't going to lie to you -- it will be *that* list of function calls that led to the variable change.  This means that if your app is multithreaded, and for some reason the call stack shows something totally weird, it isn't really weird.  You just witnessed a race condition happening in real time (stopped by the debugger).

Comment: Address sanitizer might help

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I used what the comments said and I found the issue.  First, I use Clion, and I tried to use GDB through there, and it kind of worked, but it got stuck. I'll explain what I did.

So I used the command line.

I used

```
(gdb) break my_file.h:[[line where for(std::size_t i = 0; i < packet_count; ++packet_count) is]]
```

Then I did

```
(gdb) watch shared_data_structure.semaphore_array[0]
```

And I ran the program and tried to watch.  At first I got some weird results.  First, while I was stepping through the `recvmmsg` function where it appeared that the error was originally, it *jumped* up to the function arguments of the `thread_function` lambda, then back down to where `thread_socket` was. Then, after I stepped again, everything froze in gdb for about 30 seconds (which is probably where I abandoned using Clion's GDB interface).  I think this had something to do with me not having debug-info for glibc (it warned me about that earlier) but I didn't have the ability to install debug-info stuff on my system, so while that could have helped me here, it wasn't an option.

After it froze, is spewed some python errors about it not finding the constructor debug representation for `std::array<std::unique_ptr<std::counting_semaphore<2>, std::default_deleter>, 16>`

But after it showed the value had been set at this point.  So the watch worked.

The problem was, I ran a stack trace with `bt`, and... it was just `recvmmesg` and the rest of the program, nothing deeper.

basically

```
recvmmsg()
some_std_invoke_stuff()
some_std_thread_stuff()
... all irrelevant out of scope
```

Again, debug-info probably would have helped, but at least at this point I knew it was `recvmmsg` where the problem was happening 100%.

I used Valgrind afterwards to then check the code, and after a while I saw a bunch of errors, something like "mmsghdr[633] accessed uninitialized bytes" for a bunch of consecutive values.  So I had to diagnose `mmsghdr` initialization.

I didn't include this above, because again, solving my specific problem wasn't what I wanted (and I had to write this by memory, which I didn't remember), but basically this is how the initialization looked:

```
std::array<mmsghdr, 1024> msgvec; 
std::array<iovec, 1024> iovecs; 
my::aligned_vector<std::byte, buffer_size * n> buffers; 

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i){
    iovecs[i].iov_base         = (&buffers + (i * buffer_size));
    iovecs[i].iov_len          = buffer_size;
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov    = &iovecs[i];
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
}
```

At first I thought maybe my I iterated too far, so I asserted against

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i){
    assert(buffers.size() + (i * buffer_size + buffer_size)); 
    iovecs[i].iov_base         = (&buffers + (i * buffer_size));
    iovecs[i].iov_len          = buffer_size;
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov    = &iovecs[i];
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
}
```

before I realized the real problem.  `iov_base` is a `void*`, which will accept any type of pointer.  That means  `(&buffers + (i * buffer_size))` is a pointer of  `my::aligned_vector<std::byte, buffer_size * n>`,  not a bunch of bytes.  I had to change that to `(buffers.data() + (i * buffer_size))`

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i){
    MY_ASSERT(buffers.size() + (i * buffer_size + buffer_size)); 
    iovecs[i].iov_base         = static_cast<std::byte>(buffers.data() + (i * buffer_size));
    iovecs[i].iov_len          = buffer_size;
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov    = &iovecs[i];
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
}
```

And then my problem was solved.